# How to change the index of a list in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a DataFrame and after doing some changes in the DataFrame(in fact drop some rows).Then I select a column to make a list of lists and then try to work on it. So the code is

```
st_or = list (Nsetg['Aip'][k:k+2] for k in range (0, len(Nsetg['Aip'])-1, 1)) # Nsetg is the DataFrame modified,so I select the column 'Aip'
```

But in the list I have to drop some duplicate elements, I have some code to do this and the first thing is sort the list, which give me an exception :

```
st_or.sort()
"Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects"
```

I think the problem is because the index of the elements in the list, I'm quite sure, but if I try to print the list I get something like this : `

```
print st_or
[0    0
1    1
Name: Aip, dtype: int64, 1    1
2    2
Name: Aip, dtype: int64, 2    2
3    4
Name: Aip, dtype: int64, 3    4
4    6
Name: Aip, dtype: int64]
```

What I was expecting to get after print the list is:

```
[[0,1],[1,2],[2,4],[4,6], ...,]
```

How can I get a better result ?

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible sample data set and your desired data set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `.values.tolist()`

```
st_or = list (Nsetg['Aip'].iloc[k:k+2].values.tolist()
 for k in range (0, len(Nsetg['Aip'])-1, 1))
```

Comment: @Soichiru Yw~ :-) happy coding